# move blocks between two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have two divs and inside there gona be some blocks:

```
<div class="list-block 01">
    <span>21@epos.com</span>
    <span class="moveSym" id="01">+</span>
</div>
```

if one clicks on 
   +
whole block moves to other div.
Everything works but only to move ech block to another div once, 
but I need them to go both ways as much as `.moveSym` clicked.

my JS

```
    //remove block on click
$('.del-block').on('click', function() {
    var block = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.' + block).remove();
})

//move form list blocks to different fields
$('.leftSide01 .moveSym').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).text("-");
    $('.leftSide01 .list-block.' + id).appendTo('.rightSide01');
})
$('.rightSide01 .moveSym').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).text("+");
    $('.rightSide01 .list-block.' + id).appendTo('.leftSide01');
})
```

I know there are plugins for this, but I really want to write it by myself and learn :)
Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/A1ex5andr/CRvVK/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use event delegation, because the handler to be executed depends on the parent element.

```
//move form list blocks to different fields
$('.leftSide01').on('click', '.moveSym', function () {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).text("-");
    $('.leftSide01 .list-block.' + id).appendTo('.rightSide01');
})
$('.rightSide01').on('click', '.moveSym', function () {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).text("+");
    $('.rightSide01 .list-block.' + id).appendTo('.leftSide01');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dZbLd/)

Comment: Thank you for the lesson )) it's logical, now I now about event delegation )) 
Best regards,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

You can really simplify this logic into one function that works for both (if there are only ever going to be two divs) . . .

```
$('.moveSym').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));  // I just left in, because you had it in the original code   :)

    var targetParent =  $(".rightSide01");
    var linkText = "-";

    if ($(this).parent(".rigthSide01") > 0) {
        linkText = "+";
        targetParent = $(".leftSide01");
    }

    $(this).text(linkText);
    $(this).parent().appendTo(targetParent);
});
```

This code starts out assuming that the block is on the left-hand side . . . it sets up the `targetParent` value (i.e., where the block will move to) to the right-hand side and the new link text to be "-".

After that, it checks to see if the block is actually on the right-hand side, instead, and, if it is, then it updates the variables with the values needed to move it to the left.

At that point, it updates the text in the "move-sym" `span` element to the final `linkText` value, and moves its parent block to the new target div (the `targetParent` value).

No need to worry about the delegation or event handlers in this one, because the function is the same, regardless of the location, and will travel with the "move-sym" `span` element, wherever it goes.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I understand there are better ways to implement what I need, but at the moment I need fast and simple decission. Also there may be more then one of such left/right blocks.
Any way if I have time I try to create better logic with your example.

Comment: No worries . . . the main point of my post was that you were doing a lot of extra code (some of which was even duplicate code), that could really be done with one set of common logic.  Even if there are more than two parent divs, you are really only ever doing variations of one general behavior, so you should be able to set up the HTML and JS to handle it with a single function.  If you'd like help with that, feel free to ask.   :)

Comment: hey Talemyn, i end up with this http://jsfiddle.net/A1ex5andr/dZbLd/2/ because I needed it fast )) Would you be so kind to help me make it "nice" now? ))

Comment: @A1exandr - I wish I could help . . . jsfiddle is blocked by my firewall at work, so I can't get to your code right now.